Why do I keep getting run time error 438, or 5 with this particular line
When I run this line of code
NewRbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PTRegion").ChangePivotCache (NewRbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="TableTemp"))

I receive either run time error 438 or 5. Here is the entire module:
Option Explicit

Dim myDate As Long
Dim myRegion As String

Sub Create_Reports()

    Dim tbTemp As ListObject
    Dim RowsTb As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    Call Entry_Point
    On Error GoTo Handle
    
    'create an object variable for the table inside Region Temp Tab
    
    Set tbTemp = shRegion.ListObjects("TableTemp")
    RowsTb = tbTemp.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    
    'Remove existing data in regional table except for line 1 if there is more than 1 line of data
    
    If RowsTb > 1 Then tbTemp.DataBodyRange.Rows("2:" & RowsTb).Delete
    LastRow = shAll.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    myRegion = shStart.AxRegion.Value
    myDate = Format(shAll.Range("C2").Value, "YYYYMM")
    
    'version 2 - using formula to copy data from Summary to NewData
    shAll.Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],MCompany,4,FALSE)"
    shAll.Range("I2").AutoFill Destination:=shAll.Range("I2:I" & LastRow)
    Application.Calculate

    With shAll.Range("A1:I" & LastRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=myRegion
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With

    'paste the values
    shRegion.Range("A2").PasteSpecial
     shAll.Range("A1").AutoFilter
     shAll.Columns("I").Delete

    shRegion.Range("U1").Value = myDate
    Application.Calculate
    shRegion.PivotTables("PTRegion").PivotCache.Refresh
    
    Call Region_Report
    Call Manager_Report
    Call Exit_Point
    Exit Sub
    
Handle:
'add here
    Call Exit_Point
End Sub

Private Sub Region_Report()

    Dim NewRbook As Workbook
    Dim newRpath As String
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    newRpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "RM_" & myDate & myRegion & ".xlsx"
    
    Set NewRbook = Workbooks.Add
    shRegion.Copy Before:=NewRbook.Sheets(1)
    'remove common filter for slicer
    NewRbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Company_Name").PivotTables.RemovePivotTable _
    (ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PTArticle"))
    'change pivot cache
**    **NewRbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PTRegion").ChangePivotCache (NewRbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="TableTemp"))****
    
    For Each PT In NewRbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        If PT.Name <> "PTRegion" Then
            PT.ChangePivotCache ("PTRegion")
        End If
    Next PT
    
    'add back the common slicer
NewRbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Company_Name").PivotTables.AddPivotTable _
    (ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PTArticle"))
    'some cleaning up
    With ActiveSheet
        .PivotTables("PTRegion").SaveData = True
        .Columns("AJ:AZ").Delete
        .Range("TableTemp").CurrentRegion.Columns.Group
        .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End With
    
    NewRbook.SaveAs Filename:=newRpath
    NewRbook.Close
    
End Sub


Private Sub Manager_Report()
End Sub

I'm expecting it to transfer the cache from the pivot table "PTRegion" (that I copied from another book) to the table beside it named "TableTemp".

Don't put the argument to ChangePivotCache in parentheses.  You only use parentheses when calling a function. If you're still having problems then split that line up in more steps (1) First create the pivot cache (2) pass the pivotcache to ChangePivotCache   If you get errors it's useful to include the error text and not just the number - we don't have all the codes memorized.
